# Lua for configuration over XML/Yaml/INI in .NET?

Tags: .net, configuration, lua, lua.net

I have used XML, INI and yaml files for configuration in the Python as well as in .NET C# application.

I have recently studied the lua language and tried its implementation in .NET platform. I find Lua for configuration seems to be more clean and readable. Moreover it does provide the scripting ability.

Since I heard that Lua source base is very little and it uses only Table data structure, Can I use the Lua language as my configuration file in .NET application? In this way, I can use the Lua to define my configuration, add more scripts to validate the data, add more hooks at run time.  The purpose is to bind C# and Lua.NET and still have options to read the configuration information? I saw the definition configuration file using XML & Lua and the Lua version came very neat and clear than XML version.

Comment: Similar discussion from a week ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972722/lua-vs-xml-for-data-storage

Comment: This is one of the core use cases for which Lua was created. See http://www.lua.org/history.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the Lua language as my configuration file in a .NET application?

Yes. The [Lua.NET](http://www.lua.inf.puc-rio.br/luanet/) implementation seems sufficiently mature.

The rest of your question is not quite clear to me, but

- The run-time cost is low.
- The learning curve for Lua is easy.
- It's not clear from the Lua.NET web pages exactly what the C# API is.